# How to align two fields on the same row in html page using css?

Tags: html, css, layout

have two datepickers, but they are arranged vertically.
I would like to display these two calendar pickers in a horizontal layout with some spacing in between. How can I modify them to be presented in the same row horizontally?

How can I modify them to be in the same row?

Comment: Could you add the HTML and CSS you currently have so that it could be replicated?

Comment: Use flexbox https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to place two div containers horizontal is to use

> display : flex;

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left{
   margin: 5px;
   background-color: aquamarine; 
}

.right{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="q2.css" />
    <title>2 Datepicker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <label>DatePicker1 : </label>
            <input type="date">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <label>DatePicker2 : </label>
            <input type="date">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Feel free to comment any doubt if you don't understand the code :)